# Issue with forward declaring class

Tags: c++, class, debugging

So I am trying to forward declare a class in my C++ project and then create it in main.

So I have player_obj.cpp which contains the class, classes.h which forward declares the class, and main.cpp which uses it.

classes.h

```
#ifndef CLASSES_H
#define CLASSES_H

class player_class
{
    public:

        int x;
        int y;
        char sprite;
        int xprevious;
        int yprevious;

    private:

        bool active;

    public:

        void update_xy();
        player_class(int _x, int _y, char _sprite);
        void step();
        void destroy();
};

#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "classes.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    player_class player_obj (5,5,'#');
    cout << player_obj.x << ", " << player_obj.y << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and player_obj.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

class player_class
{
    public:

        //Coordinates
        int x;
        int y;

        //Sprite
        char sprite;

        //Previous coordinates
        int xprevious;
        int yprevious;

    //Not everyone can set the activity
    private:

        //Active
        bool active;

    //Update xprevious and yprevious - Called by the step event
    void update_xy()
    {
        xprevious = x;
        yprevious = y;
    }

    //All functions public  
    public:

        //Create event/Constructer
        player_class(int _x, int _y, char _sprite)
        {
            //Set default variables
            x = _x;
            y = _y;
            sprite = _sprite;
            xprevious = x;
            yprevious = y;
            active = true;
        }

        //Step event
        void step()
        {
            //Update old xprevious and yprevious
            update_xy();

            //Do other stuff here

        }

        //Drestroy event
        void destroy()
        {
            active = false;
        }
};
```

I thought that would work out all right but when I compile and run it I get:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to`player_class::player_class(int, int, char)'
```

I've done some research, but I can't seem to fix this issue.

I greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: There are many things wrong in this code. I would *highly* recommend checking out a good C++ book and just working through it.

Comment: The starting point you should take is to see how your code in "player_obj.cpp" violates the [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)

Comment: `class player_class;` is a forward declaration. What you have is a full definition.

Comment: Wait, but how would I forward declare the class in a header file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you're sort of close, what you have in your header is indeed a class declaration (not a forward declaration mind you).

The problem is you never defined it. What you have in `player_obj.cpp` is an abomination of class redefinition, but you already have your class declared. Just include the header file and define the functions one by one and you're done!

```
    #include "classes.h"

    player_class::player_class(int _x, int _y, char _sprite)
    {
        //Set default variables
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
        sprite = _sprite;
        xprevious = x;
        yprevious = y;
        active = true;
    }

    // and so on
```

If you're serious about learning modern C++ though, a few notes:

- `#pragma once` is the modern way of guarding header files. Don't use those `#ifdef..#endif` constructs.
- generally speaking, don't name anything starting with underscores. Especially not parameters visible as part of your public contract.
- you have class initializers for a reason, use them! You don't need half a screen of copy pasting variables in your constructors.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do some research on #pragma once and fix up the identifier name.

Comment: `#pragma once`, which is non-standard and not supported by all compilers, is not preferable to the standard include guards.

Comment: @TC I didn't say it was standard, I said it was modern. It's supported by literally every compiler in everyday use, but 10 years later someone still brings that up.

Answer (score 0):

You dont want a forward declaration. You want a declaration. It is a classical case of declaring a class in a header file and defining its functions in a cpp file. Then including the header where-ever you want to use your class

You only need forward declarations when you want to use a pointer to that class as a parameter to a function or a member variable somewhere but the definition of that class is not available yet.
Note that when you forward declare a class, you cannot use this class's member variables or functions in that header

-regards
Gautam